# Routing requests away from an unhealthy (503ing) instance?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

We have a Web App hosted on multiple (scaled-out) Premium Dv2 instances using Azure App Service.

Occasionally our application fails to start-up after a restart. This will result in a `503 Service Unavailable` response for requests to that instance. But when this happens, requests still get routed evenly between this instance and the healthy instances.

Shouldn't the load-balancer rather route requests away from this instance? Can this be achieved?

NOTE: We are not using API Management or App Service Environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't the load-balancer rather route requests away from this instance?

Azure Load Balancer can probe the health of the various server instances. When a probe fails to respond, the load balancer stops sending new connections to the unhealthy instances.

AFAIK, before you get 503 error, it still get routed to that instance.

> But when this happens, requests still get routed evenly between this instance and the healthy instances.

I found the following possible scenes that you still get routed when the instances are unhealthy.

1.The timeout and frequency values set in **SuccessFailCount** determine whether an instance is confirmed to be running or not running. In the Azure portal, the timeout is set to two times the value of the frequency.

2.The HTTP server doesn't respond at all after the timeout period. Depending on the timeout value that is set, multiple probe requests might go unanswered before the probe gets marked as not running.

3.If you have web roles that use w3wp.exe, you also get automatic monitoring of your website. Failures in your website code return a non-200 status to the load balancer probe.Consequently, the load balancer doesn't take that instance out of rotation.

4.The TCP server doesn't respond at all after the timeout period. When the probe is marked as not running depends on the number of failed probe requests that were configured to go unanswered before marking the probe as not running.

For more detail, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-custom-probe-overview).